# DataTable sorting date with JQuery

Tags: jquery, sorting, date, jquery-plugins, datatable

Yo everyone,

I wanna sort some dates "desc" and "asc" but I've got :
**01/10/2014

09/10/2014

23/09/2014
... (Listed by day)**

What I used :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/a5734b29083/sorting/date-euro.js"></script>
```

I solved my prob with :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            "aoColumns" :[
                            { "sType": "date-euro", "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]], "bSortable":true  },
                            null,
                            null,
                            null
                        ]});

} );
```

But now : 
**09/10/2014

01/10/2014

23/09/2014
... (Listed by month, and by day)**
 and the sort is disabled.
I'm totally lost about the step to follow to solve this.

NB1: I'm using AngularJS :

```
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$route', function ($scope,$route) {
```

NB2: my dates are generated by a *date_create* and *date_format* from mySQL format.


Thanks in advance for the helps.

**WORKING RESULT** :

I've found a solution :
my new .js file :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

} );
```

and in my HTML / PHP I wrote in my date column :

```
<?php
    $date = date_create($row[0]);
    echo "
    <small hidden>".date_format($date, 'U')."</small> 
    ".date_format($date, 'd/m/Y H:i:s').";
?>
```

explications :

 *date_create* : take the DATETIME value stocked in column 1 in mySql to be formatted

 *date_format* : change the date format as you wish

 *U* : timestamp value, difference between your date value and 01/01/1970 (ex : 1225972800 = 06/11/2008)

" small hidden " doesn't appear but is used to sort the date because it's the first value of the column.

Comment: Good solution, I'm surprised Data tables doesn't have a way to provide pre-formatted data to the sorting function.